# Reliability of USB cable

Tags: usb, usb-2

MICROCHIP USB3300:
   1. How many write or erase cycles is the device recommended for during its life span?
   2. How many years the data written is assured to be retained? (Data retention)

Please Share.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This device does not retain data at all, and therefore doesn't have write cycles. It is only a transceiver used for adding USB connection capability to *other* manufactured devices.

Comment: How many maximum read cycles can it do during its lifetime?

Comment: Does it have read cycles?